# How install the UserHelp add-on?

Tags: application

**How to install `UserHelp`**

I'm totally baffled about how to install the parent add-on, `UserHelp` of `YuK`. And in particular, how to get Mathematica to recognize the documentation pages for `UserHelp`, e.g., how to get Wolfram Documentation's list of installed add-ons to include `UserHelp`.

Can anybody help here?

I note that `UserHelp` comes inside a folder `mma_userhelp` which in turn contains a readme.txt that explains that the add-on does not have to be placed in any particular location and that the `install.nb` notebook there takes care of this. But I do not understand how to get the packages, and their documentation, into `~/Library/Mathematica/Applications`.

**Original post**

I find in my `~/Library/Mathematica/Autoload` folder (macOS) a subfolder named `YuK`. That subfolder, in turn, has a subfolder `Kernel` with the following `init.m`:

```
 Get["/Users/myaccount/Downloads/userhelp-master/mma_userhelp/YuK/Kernel/Init.m"]
```

Evidently that was installed automatically from some add-on that was packaged either in the conventional way, to go into `~/Library/Mathematica/Applications` or, more likely, in a paclet.

What add-on is this and what is its source?

(I've searched for "userhelp" and "YuK" elsewhere in `~/Library/Mathematica` but have not found anything. And there's nothing called "YuK" at http://packagedata.net/index.php.

Comment: https://github.com/yurkan/userhelp

Comment: "or, more likely, in a paclet" I just wanted to point out that packages distributed as *paclets* don't really have any reason to do things like this, as most things that could be achieved through such means (e.g. installation or automatic loading) are already supported by the paclet manager.